# Iterate through multiple iterators at same time in special order

Tags: php, algorithm, iterator

Lets say I have two iterators:

```
$a = new ArrayIterator(array(4, 3, 2));
$b = new ArrayIterator(array(6, 5, 1));
```

Now I want to iterate them in a way to output the following:

```
 a b sum

 4 6  10 
 4 5  9 
 3 6  9 
 3 5  8 
 2 6  8 
 2 5  7 
 4 1  5 
 3 1  4 
 2 1  3
```

So I want to iterate through all possible combinations. Additionally I want it in a way that the ones with the summed highest value will come first.

I don't want to use arrays (so also no array sorting), I need to do it with iterators (because of constraints from my original case).

Comment: "I don't want to use arrays" Is there an actual technical reason here? I don't know of any solution that's going to have O(1) words of extra storage.

Comment: I don't think this is possible without sorting. Look at the pairs `(index-in-a;index-in-b)`, the first three pairs are `(0;1)`, `(0;2)`, `(2;1)` - it is completely unpredictable. You could consider using a sorted list implementation, so that the pairs are inserted into the result list based on their sum, however such list has larger insertion time complexity and you may be better off with sorting.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat The input iterators are generators in my original code. They are also coming in parts from a database and can be huge, so I want to avoid to put them in arrays. Esp. because it will happen often that I will abort the iteration early (and so I don't need to read everything out of the DB first).

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak I changed the requirements. Now the input is already sorted (sorry my fault). Makes this things easier? My gut feeling tells me it can be possible, however I am not totally sure either.

Comment: @flori Yep, now you can do this with time complexity n + m (where n and m are lengths of the iterators). Let's say that current indices are `i` and `j` for iterators `a` and `b` respectively. 1. Process pair `(i, j)` 2. If `a[i+1] - a[i] > b[j+1] - b[j]` then `j++`, otherwise `i++`. 3. Repeat. There are also edge cases such as when you reach the end of one iterator.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak Thanks! Yes, this end of iterator will be a bit tricky. How to make sure to get all combinations and don't produce duplicates by reiterating too much?

Comment: @flori You won't end up with duplicates because you iterate one way only and never go back. These two simple rules can help you: 1. In each iteration (iteration, step, recursive call, whatever) process data exactly once (e.g. print the sum) 2. In each iteration increase either `i` or `j`, if both are at the end then terminate

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak Thank you, you are right! Sadly my real code has three iterators. In that case, I assume at the moment, it isn't possible. Sorry, it was my fault to reduce the example too much.

Comment: @flori If you have sums of three numbers and three sorted iterators it's really all the same. The biggest difference is that instead of one if-statement you will need 3. You will need to find the smallest difference `k[i+1] - k[i]' among all iterators (`k` is iterator and `i` is its current index of iteration) and progress this iterator by one element. All other rules stay the same.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak Yes, that works. I got stuck at the problem that when one iterator is somewhere in the middle and another one at the end, I rewind the latter one. However then I get duplicates or missing combinations and I can't find a clever way to avoid that (without intermediate arrays).

Comment: @flori what do you mean that you rewind it? once it reached the end it should not be used anymore, the algorithm continues with the other two iterators (and uses the last value from the third iterator)

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak Otherwise I am missing combinations. Lets say my first of three iterators holds `3` and `2`, my last one `4` and `1*. If the first iterator hits the end before the last one was triggered, I never get the combination `3-1`.

Comment: @flori Yes, you are right, I have just realized it.

Answer (score 0):

It's your required ordering that throws things. You can't do it without some form of sort; but a heap datastructure may be an option:

```
$a = new ArrayIterator(array(4, 2, 3));
$b = new ArrayIterator(array(1, 6, 5));

class MyHeap extends SplHeap {
    public function compare($v1, $v2) {
        if ($v1->sum === $v2->sum) return 0;
        return $v1->sum < $v2->sum ? -1 : 1;
    }
}

$heap = new MyHeap();
foreach($a as $val1) {
    foreach($b as $val2) {
        $heap->insert(
            (object) [
                'val1' => $val1,
                'val2' => $val2,
                'sum' => $val1+$val2
            ]
        );
    }
}

$heap->top();
foreach($heap as $value) {
  echo $value->val1, ' ', $value->val2, ' ', $value->sum, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Sorting is okay. I just don't want to pile up first everything in arrays. I want the sorting "on the fly" ;-)
See also my upper comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29104680#comment46441262_29104680